# Writing a value to an already open workbook using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel workbook that has a button, that triggers a c# application. I need to add the returned value from the app to the excel workbook but I can't figure out how to do that while the excel workbook is already open.

I've basically been grasping at straws. Every example I've found opens a read only version of the excel workbook

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application myExcelApp;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook myExcelWorkbook = new 
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

xlWorkSheet = myExcelWorkbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
xlWorkSheet = myExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

myExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
myExcelApp =
   (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook item in myExcelApp.Workbooks)
{
    //Select the excel target 'NAME'
    if (item.Name == "DatagridviewTest.xlsm")
    {
        myExcelWorkbook = item;
        break;
    }

    //Select the target workbook                
    xlWorkSheet = myExcelWorkbook.Sheets[1] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

    //Set cell value
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 1] = "new value";
}
```

I get an unhandled exception error "System runtime COM exception"

Comment: How are you getting the value back from the C# program? Could you switch it around and open the workbook from C# in the first place, rather than running a C# program from the workbook?

Comment: If your program did not open the Excel file, then it is owned by another process from the OS’s perspective hence the read only. Is there some reason you don’t close the Excel file before you run your code?